# Auth Activity returns to my app, not system Setting

Tags: android

I've implemented an AccountAuthenticator according to the docs, as far as I can tell.  It returns an `Intent` for a login activity that is part of my app.  The system seems to work as expected, except in one use case:  If I use the system Settings' Account panel to add my account, when I dismiss my login activity (it explicitly calls `finish()`) the next activity is sometimes an activity from my app: I am not returned to system Settings.  I believe this happens only when I navigate to system Settings directly from my app.

Specifically: User starts my app.  User backs out to desktop.  User starts system Settings.  User uses system Settings to create one of my app's accounts.  That starts a login activity in my app.  The login activity calls `finish()`.  Next up is my app, not system Settings.

Here's the `<activity>` declaration from my manifest:

```
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

What do I need to do to make it so that when invoked from Settings, I always return to Setting?

Comment: This feels like a task issue. Make sure that you are launching the Settings app in a separate task from your app's task. BTW, hi! :-)

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare!  Yea, right?  I'm not starting Settings, though. Edited to clarify the use case.

Comment: Ah, OK. "I believe this happens only when I navigate to system Settings directly from my app" was what I based my original comment on. Are you doing anything funky task-wise in your login activity? (e.g., `launchMode` or `taskAffinity` attributes on the `<activity>` element). Your symptoms would be explained by your login activity forcing the user into a different task than the Settings app task.

Comment: I don't think so.  Confirmed: stop app; create account via settings; auto-return to settings.  Start app from desktop; return to desktop; create app via settings; auto-return to app.  Edited to show main activity config.